# Task manager that can kill more than one process at once on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, task-management

I am looking for a GUI task manager for Windows 7 that can kill more than one process at once.

What I am aware of:

- Windows 7's native task manager only allows to select one process at once.
- The CLI program [taskkill](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html), which can end one or more processes (by process id or image name) (e.g. `taskkill /im putty.exe` will kill all `putty.exe` processes)

Any price or license is fine.

Comment: far manager has plugin that allows navivation through running process. You may select several of them as they were files and kill them at once

Comment: @ayvango Thanks, http://www.farmanager.com/ ? and do you recall the plug-in's name?

Comment: AFAIK it is included in base distribution. could be accessed from disk choice menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use the Resource Monitor that comes with Windows 7, and which is only few clicks away? This allows to select and then kill multiple processes simultaneously. To call it just navigate to the performance tab in the Windows task manager and click on the button labelled "Resource Monitor" at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea the resource monitor could kill multiple processes simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

I personally use and can recommend [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/). It's a full featured task manager closely inspired by the famous Process Explorer.

Relevant to the question, it can kill multiple processes at once. Its main screen includes a list of processes:

[image: Process Hacker process list]

It supports the standard multi-selection methods of ctrl+click and shift+click to chose processes for manipulation or termination. It also offers to kill all child processes from a parent. It's released under the GPLv3 license.

Other features, unimportant to the question but nice to have, are ability to manipulate services, detailed disk and network activity and many information and manipulation of process internals.

Answer (score 3):

[KillProcess](http://orangelampsoftware.com/products_killprocess.php) can do that.

> KillProcess is an application assassin of the extreme kind. It can
>   terminate almost any process on a Windows machine, including any
>   service and process running in the system. Even protected Microsoft
>   system processes can be terminated. All of this can be done in the
>   matter of milliseconds.
>
> **It can kill multiple processes, either by multi-select or by clever
>   use of “kill lists”.** Using these techniques it is possible to “batch”
>   terminate processes, quickly and swiftly, with a click of a button.

Here's an example while I was about to kill notepad and powershell at the same time:

[image: KillProcess in action]

The program is freeware; it works on several versions of Windows, including Windows 7.